# Getting the empty response from the server even when the container is port mapped in docker

Tags: docker, httpserver

I am trying to start my application using the http-server through npm start. It is working fine in the localhost but when i deploy the same application through docker container (port-mapped) , it doesn't appear in my local browser.

I have a directory inside my docker container(Ubuntu) which is runned through the command
 `docker run -it -p 8001:5500 ubuntu`.
I have installed everything inside my container - npm, vim editor ,etc.

My package.json file is

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 5500"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.0.2",
    "http-server": "^0.12.1"
  }
}
```

After that i have done `npm install` and then executed the command `npm start`.
The output of the command is :

[image]

But when i am trying to open my application in chrome browser it is throwing me an empty response.

[image]

Also when i am running the same application through my localhost it is accessible. 
[image]

Why i am not able to access the server through the port mapping of docker container.??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`localhost` inside container won't be accessible from outside the container. Run your server on `0.0.0.0` inside the container.

Comment: Yass.. Solved.. Thanks a lot.. I wonder why localhost isn't supported inside the container.?

Comment: When a container is created, it runs in a different network namespace by default. So the `localhost` interface inside container is different from `localhost` interface on the host.